# Similar to `by`, but for other methods than get/set methods

Tags: kotlin

I only just discovered the `by` keyword for `class`, and it seems that it only works for get/set methods. But what about other methods? For example, in the code below, if I omit `override fun suggestSelection(...}`, it does not seem to return `fallback.suggestSelection(text, selectionStartIndex, selectionEndIndex, defaultLocales);`. As you see, all it does is calling the same method in `fallback` with the same argument. Is this the only way or is there anything to make `fallback` automatically called for this?

```
inner class MyTextClassfier(private val fallback:TextClassifier) : TextClassifier by fallback
{
    override fun suggestSelection(
        text: CharSequence,
        selectionStartIndex: Int,
        selectionEndIndex: Int,
        defaultLocales: LocaleList?
    ): TextSelection
    {
        return fallback.suggestSelection(text, selectionStartIndex, selectionEndIndex, defaultLocales);
    }
```

---

Adding full code as requested below. It needs the default generated Android project structure by Android Studio.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.stackoverflow.test

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.LocaleList
import android.util.Log
import android.view.textclassifier.TextClassification
import android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager
import android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifier
import android.view.textclassifier.TextSelection
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textClassificationManager = getSystemService(Context.TEXT_CLASSIFICATION_SERVICE) as TextClassificationManager;
        val defaultOne = textClassificationManager.textClassifier;
        val txt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview1);
        txt.setTextClassifier(MyTextClassfier(defaultOne));
    }

    inner class MyTextClassfier(private val fallback:TextClassifier) : TextClassifier by fallback
    {
        override fun suggestSelection(
            text: CharSequence,
            selectionStartIndex: Int,
            selectionEndIndex: Int,
            defaultLocales: LocaleList?
        ): TextSelection
        {
            return fallback.suggestSelection(text, selectionStartIndex, selectionEndIndex, defaultLocales);
            //return TextSelection.Builder(0,0).build();
        }

        override fun classifyText(
            text: CharSequence,
            startIndex: Int,
            endIndex: Int,
            defaultLocales: LocaleList?
        ): TextClassification
        {
            //Selection ended. User has lifted his finger.
            Log.d("stack", "classifyText is called.");
            return TextClassification.Builder().build();
        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:text="@string/large_text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You shouldn’t have to override the function at all. Can you share the code that demonstrates the unwanted behavior.

Comment: *it seems that it only works for get/set methods* - that is incorrect. Interface delegation works for all methods of the interface. I agree with @Tenfour04, maybe you should share the unwanted behavior that led you to this conclusion

Comment: @Tenfour04 On Android 8.1, if I do not override it, the following runtime exception occurs: Java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "android.view.textclassifier.TextSelection android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifier.suggestSelection(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int, android.os.LocaleList)". On Android 10/11/12, it was fine not to override it.

Comment: Appended the full code to the original post.